# react-native-elements avatar - problem with fallback to title on IOS if image doesn't exist

Tags: react-native, avatar, react-native-elements

I'm using a cloud based storage for avatar images. If an image for a user doesn't exist I want to fallback to the user title.The code below works for android, but on IOS the image is just blank and no title.

`<Avatar rounded source={{ uri: avatarUrl }} title={userName.slice(0, 2)} />`

On a regular Image you can use onError to handle this, but I don't see how I can use this on the Avatar.

Anyone have any suggestions how to fix this? or another package that handles it better?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having a similar problem, but leftAvatar and on Android! I did not test it on iOS.